# Update current View MVC 5 after save

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code and want to update the user role with dropdown then stay on this page with the updated choice from the dropdown. I thought I could use redirectToAction to the GET ActonResult but it goes to the POST ActionResult. How do I stay on the same view with the dropdown updated with new choice? Thanks

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Details(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);

        EmployeeViewModel empv = new EmployeeViewModel();
        empv.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
        empv.LastName = employee.LastName;
        empv.NetworkLoginID = employee.NetworkLoginID;
        empv.PersonID = employee.PersonID;
        empv.DataStatusID = employee.DataStatusID;
        empv.EmployeeGUID = employee.EmployeeGUID;




        Guid UserRoleGuid = (from e in db.EmployeeToUserRoles
                           where e.EmployeeGUID == empv.EmployeeGUID
                             select e.RoleGUID).FirstOrDefault();



        empv.RoleID = UserRoleGuid;

        if (employee == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        } 
        PopulatedDropDown(empv.RoleID);

        return View(empv);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(Guid EmployeeGUID, Guid Roles)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            EmployeeToUserRole emp = new EmployeeToUserRole();
            //check if employee was in role and update column

            var inrole = from d in db.EmployeeToUserRoles
                         where d.EmployeeGUID == EmployeeGUID                       
                         select d.EmployeeRoleGUID;

            int count = inrole.Count();

            if (count > 0  )
            {
                emp = db.EmployeeToUserRoles.Where(s => s.EmployeeGUID == EmployeeGUID).FirstOrDefault<EmployeeToUserRole>();

                emp.RoleGUID = Roles;
                db.Entry(emp).State = EntityState.Modified;


                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            else
            { 

            emp.EmployeeRoleGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
            emp.RoleGUID = Roles;
            emp.EmployeeGUID = EmployeeGUID;

            db.EmployeeToUserRoles.Add(emp);
            db.SaveChanges();
            }


            PopulatedDropDown(Roles);

            RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = emp.EmployeeGUID });

        }

        return View();


    }
```

Comment: How do you render the dropdown in your razor ?

Comment: I'm using a ViewBag with a DropDownList(). I also have the employeeGuid in a HiddenFor(m => m.EmployeeGUID) inside the Form tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the RedirectToAction Result.

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = emp.EmployeeGUID });
```

This will make the browser to do a GET request to the Details action with the value of  `emp.EmployeeGUID`. You need to set the corresponding property (for the role) of your view model in that after reading the Employee entity from your db.